# Tomcat issue with url-pattern

Tags: java, security, url, tomcat

In my web.xml of my simple app i have

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Hai</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and now if I have

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

in security constraint it asks for password when I try to get to my deployed app, but when I change it to

```
<url-pattern>/Projekt/*</url-pattern>
```

and try to enter Projekt/Hai I am not asked for my password, why?

Comment: Under which context path is your application deployed, and what's the complete URL you're using when it doesn't ask for a password?

Comment: <Context docBase="Projekt.war" path="/Projekt"/>, I use localhost:8080/Projekt/Hai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url-pattern that you specify in web.xml is always a pattern that is relative to the context path of the webapp. So, `/Projekt/*` means all the URLs under `/Projekt`, **under the context path of the application**.

Since your app is deployed un `/Projekt`, it means that this url-pattern matches the URL `http://localhost:8080/Projekt/projekt/Hai`. It doesn't match `http://localhost:8080/Projekt/Hai`, because this URL, when written relatively to the context path, is `/Hai`, which doesn't matches the pattern `/Projekt/*`.

Good rule of thumb: nothing in the code or deployment descriptor of a webapp should ever depend on the context path chosen to deploy the application. Everything should always be specified relatively to this context path.